# JavaScript DOM parent/child relation on mouse event

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseover, mouseout

O.K. Maybe I have asked something similar to this, but this is another problem I have. I will start by showing the code:

```
var MyClass = {
    // Set up the events for the parent
    // MyParent is a DIV
    SetEvents: function() {
         MyParent.onmouseover = function() { MyClass.MouseHover(MyParent); };
         MyParent.onmouseout = function() { MyClass.MouseOut(MyParent); };
    },

    // Function activated when moving the mouse over the parent
    MouseHover: function(Parent) {
        if (Parent) {
        // Here I create the child, when moving the mouse over the parent control
        // The child is an IMG
            var child = document.createElement("img");
                child.id = "child";
                child.src = "child.png";
                child.style.float = "right";
            Parent.appendChild(child);
        }
    },

    // Function activated when moving the mouse out of the parent control
    MouseOut: function(Parent) {
        if (Parent) {
            var child = document.getElementById("child");
            if (child) {
                // On mouse out I remove the child
                Parent.removeChild(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, this is just about a simple image appearing when I move the mouse over a `div`, then disappears when I move the mouse out. Yet, this is not behaving as I want.

The problem is that when, while the mouse is over the parent `div`, if I move it over the child `img` (still over the parent), the `MouseOut()` function is fired.

I have been searching for solutions and tricks all these days but everything was in vain. Now, I hope somebody can identify the problem. There must be some JavaScript chapter that I missed out. Thanks to everybody!

I added some images, to explain this better

[image: Case 1]
[image: Case 2]
[image: Case 3]
[image: Case 4]

**UPDATES**
Looks like this happens only when the IMG child is created dinamically. If I create it before and only change it's src, it works.

**JSSFIDLE DEMO**
You can see this script working (well, not working, better said) at http://jsfiddle.net/E9q6e/1/

Comment: Could you possibly include a live demo, using [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, to show us what you're working with in action?

Comment: David Thomas: http://jsfiddle.net/E9q6e/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check, if `Parent` contains the `child` in `MouseOut()`:

```
var ref=event.toElement || event.relatedTarget; // This line is pseudocode
if(!Parent.contains(ref)){
  Parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: If you try this on http://jsfiddle.net/E9q6e/1/ (my script), the MouseOut will be totally disabled

Comment: In IE it works as it is (depends on how you've assigned the eventhandler). For other browsers you'll need to get a reference to the Event-object. Notice the remark : "This line is pseudocode".